# embed code web part image not showing

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Form from the forms app i have use in the embed web part in SharePoint.  It was all working fine and web part automatically embedded the form with the form picture.  We go moved to the GCC cloud last week and now the form embeds but i get a green background where the picture once was.  Any idea how to get he picture back?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MS forms or a 3rd party forms app? For MS forms, there are [forms web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-microsoft-forms-web-part-d4b4d3ce-7860-41e4-8a98-76380efe7256) available for you to directly use the form.

As you are using GCC cloud now. It may be better to open a service request about this issue.